# RecyclerView.ViewHolder communicating with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, screen-orientation, android-viewholder

I need to find a way for a recyclerview to tell a fragment when a certain type of post is shown on the screen. I'm having trouble developing a generalized method for determining if and how many video posts are shown on the screen at any given point in time. What I want is for the fragment to at least know when a video post (along with their state) is on the screen so that the activity can become unlocked from portrait mode so that on rotation the VideoView takes up the entire screen instead of a small part of it (assuming the video is playing). Given the situation where there is more than one video post shown, when one is started while the other is playing, I want the one playing to stop and the other video post to start playing. The logic for controlling video playback is in the viewholder class. How would I go about setting up this functionality?

Comment: Probably your best bet is to make callbacks. You implement an interface on your fragment and pass ti along to the ViewHolder, through the RecyclerView.Adapter. When the video is playing the view holder could call said callback and let the fragment know that the video is playing as well as which video is playing if you have IDs for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a interface was the way to go. I also looked up EventBus, but apparently those types of mechanisms are used for when you have one component sending messages to multiple recipients (as opposed to when you implement a listener, which is for a one to one connection).